# Prevent automatic show and focus of the 1st window when the 2nd window gets hidden

Tags: electron

```
let firstWin = new BrowserWindow()
let secondWin = new BrowserWindow()

secondWin.hide()
```

Let's assume there are three active windows. Two of them belong to my application (`firstWin` and `secondWin`). The third one is Chrome (or any other application). `firstWin` is at the bottom of the hierarchy, Chrome in the middle and `secondWin` on top.

secondWin 
Chrome 
firstWin

When I call `secondWin.hide()`, `firstWin` automatically pops up and gets focused. The result is then:

firstWin 
Chrome

Is there any way to prevent that? I would like `firstWin` to not pop up but stay at the bottom of the window hierarchy when I hide `secondWin`.

Comment: Window management *can* depend on the OS, would you mind sharing which OS you're on?

Comment: I’m on macOS. Ideally I would look for a solution that works on Windows as well :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be able to listen to a window's `focus` and/or `show` events (see https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window)

You could then make "a decision" to immediately call hide() on that window. (I suppose there is a chance of it flashing on screen briefly.)

(How to make that decision is a bit tricky; I suppose you could record the time you called `secondWin.hide()` and use the number of seconds since then to decide... not ideal!)

As another approach, just before calling `secondWin.hide()` you could [look at the current state](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winisminimized) of `firstWin`, and if that is minimized or hidden, you could instead call `app.hide()` (see https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apphide-macos).

(Unless you always want *all* windows hidden when one window is hidden, this  isn't going to scale very nicely beyond 2 windows, unfortunately.)

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts Darren. I considered both of these options as well but ultimately rejected them for the same reasons you mentioned (1: window is flashing, 2: all windows get closed). I will write down the solution I went with and then see if anyone else comes up with something more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that I went with for now is to set the opacity of the window to zero and deactivate mouse events. That would be

```
secondWin.setOpacity(0); 
secondWin.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true);
```

instead of

```
secondWin.hide()
```

You then reverse the settings whenever you want the window to become visible again. It's a bit hacky but works for now. Let's see if anyone finds a better solution. Ideally there would be an event like `window-about-to-be-shown`, which you can plug into and call `event.preventDefault()` on.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the last answer but here is how I solved this issue:

setting

```
firstWin.setFocusable(false)
```

just before calling

```
secondWin.hide()
```

will prevent the first window from getting focused.

After that, you can restore the focusable state again calling

```
firstWin.setFocusable(true)
```